# Assembly 8086 Keyboard shift flag always returns 0

Tags: assembly, interrupt, dosbox, keyboardinterrupt

so recently I have attempted to make a keylogger for my school project. (I changed int9h to my own code, so that I can get the keys without interrupting the keyboard buffer or other programs). Now when using regular keys (Just plain bios codes) everything works but I have a problem with the keyboard shift flag status. 
I tried to get the byte both using int16h (ah=2) and straight from memory and I tried printing it to see what's wrong. The byte is always 0 no matter which key I press (Lshift, Rshift, Caps lock etc.).

Note: We are using DOSbox to run our programs

This is my check:

```
shiftRight_check: 
mov ah, 2
int 16h
test al, 1
jz shiftLeft_check
jmp shift_keys

shiftLeft_check: 
mov ah, 2
int 16h
test al, 2
jz regular_keys
jmp shift_keys
```

From what I saw the byte should be as follows:

```
 0:  01H alpha-shift (right side) DOWN
 1:  02H alpha-shift (left side) DOWN
 2:  04H Ctrl-shift (either side) DOWN
 3:  08H Alt-shift  (either side) DOWN
 4:  10H ScrollLock state
 5:  20H NumLock state
 6:  40H CapsLock state
 7:  80H Insert state
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your `int 9h` handler is probably destroying some internal BIOS state making the original handler to produce invalid results. It's hard to tell, as you didn't post your keyboard handler. (and if you are doing those `int 16h` inside the keyboard handler, then that's usually invalid approach, to call other interrupt from one handler, you should try to avoid that and get the shift flags directly from the internal BIOS keyboard handler structure (I guess you are still using the original handler chained to your own `int 9` handler, and your handler does just mirror the data processed by original?).

Comment: To verify, try that `int 16h, ah=2` first without your handler installed, on normal BIOS handler, if it works as expected, you know the issue is your handler. If it doesn't work, then http://www.stanislavs.org/helppc/int_16-2.html is broken in dosbox, but that's like 0.1% probability, search for your bug first.